# Expandable list view with text view

Tags: android

I want a expandable list view for displaying notification. if user clicks a specific notification the list view should expand showing more details about notification.I have implemented expandable list view with child list view for each item. I require child view as a text view instead of list view. please provide with suggestions

Comment: I have implemented the expandable list view from this tutorials.....    http://mobileappsresource.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html   i want to replace the child list view with custom textview

Comment: you have customized adapter friend then it weill be easy

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use a customized child view for the expanadable list, where you want to have only a text view. You need to customize the child row such that it should contain only a text view.

see my blogpost on [How to use Expandable List in Android](http://androidsourcecodemj.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-use-expandable-list-in-android.html). It will help you to create the child view as you want.